# Calculating x users of total users - count vs. sum

Tags: sql, google-bigquery

I have to calculate the percentage of total daily users that are x_users. X_users are defined as those in column y with records that isnull or ='null'. Isnull is a null record and 'null' is the string - both are in my tables.

For simplicity, I provided a shortened example (minus all the dimensions and group bys) of my query and subquery below.

Sample query

```
COUNT (DISTINCT (CASE
        WHEN event_name ='launch' THEN user_id
    END
      )) AS daily_users,
SUM(is_null + null_str) as x_users
```

Sample subquery

```
if(column_y is null,1,0) as is_null,
if(column_y = 'null',1,0) as null_str
```

However, when I run this query, I am resulting in a table where my number of x_users are much higher than the daily user. That is not correct since the type of user (in this case, x_users) should be lower than the total users.

Sample final table

| User | country | daily_users | x_users |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | US | 5 | 12 |
| 2 | UK | 10 | 18 |

Can anyone help point me in the right direction? Any help is appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: I'm lost.  What is an "x_user"?  What is NULL?  Sample data and desired results would help.

Answer (score 0):

I speculate that you want something like this:

```
COUNT(DISTINCT CASE WHEN event_name = 'launch' THEN user_id END) as daily_users,
COUNT(DISTINCT CASE WHEN event_name = 'launch' AND (is_null > 0 OR null_str > 0) THEN user_id END) as daily_x_users,
```

Comment: Hi Gordon. Thanks for the quick reply. However, the is_null and str_null come from another column - column y - and not event name.

Comment: @toriafterhours . . . This doesn't imply that they come form "event name".  That wouldn't even make sense.

Comment: I understand, thank you. In that case, I should have a subquery that assigns a 'null' string value to those column_y that isnull. 

Then in the main query, it should look like this: 

COUNT(DISTINCT (CASE WHEN event_name = 'launch' AND column_y = 'null' THEN user_id END)) as daily_x_user 

Does this look correct to you?